# Jmeter Junit return error NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: maven, junit, jmeter

running my JUnit tests from InteliJ and it working
after trying to run it from Jmeter Junit sampler I have error

Error -- myTest(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): com.myname.dao.utilities.MyUtilities.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
Trace -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.myname.dao.utilities.MyUtilities.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;

I have Jar with several 3rd party dependencies (from Maven Install) in $JMETER_HOME\lib\junit
and I see log4j dependency in .

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has its own SL4J logger implementation, as for my JMeter 2.12 there are following classes in /lib folder of JMeter installation:

- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar

If your unit test relies on different version, I would suggest to use the one which is shipped with JMeter.

In regards to libraries location:

- /lib/junit - for JUnit tests
- /lib/ext - for JMeter libraries and modules including custom plugins
- /lib - for all dependency libraries
- jar, multiple jars, folder or combination of aforementioned can be also used for specifying lookup locations

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: The calls to Logger.class are not from my junit code it is from java code that I need to test

Comment: In that case I'm afraid your question has nothing in common with JMeter.

Comment: May be ... But those Junits successfully run from IntelliJ and failed in Jmeter